# visual estudio no deja que el usuario defina el tamaño del vector en c++;

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2022

estaba programando ejercisios basicos en visual studio y este codigo me da error y dice que trabajo no es una constante pero si lo compilo con otro ide como devc++ no me da error quiero saber por que sucede esto:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int trabajos, nota_final;
    
    cout << "cuantos trabajos te mando el profe";
    cin >> trabajos;

    int nota[trabajos];

    nota_final = 0;
    cout << "digita tus notas"<<endl;
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < trabajos; i++)
    {
        cin >> nota[i];
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < trabajos; i++)
    {
        nota_final = nota[i] + nota_final;
    }


    nota_final = nota_final / trabajos;

    cout << nota_final;
}
```

Comment: que compilador estas usando?

Comment: Tal vez podrías usar vectores de C++ en vez de arreglos de C. Tienes que agregar `#include <vector>` al inicio, y luego crear el vector escribiendo `vector<int> nota(trabajos);`

Comment: Hola Daniel, lo probé en NetBeans y funciona, has probado otros programas en Visual?.

Comment: uso el compilador por defecto de vs para c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int notas[trabajos];
```

Eso es un arreglo, [array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array) o formación de tamaño variable y el estándar los prohibe. Los arreglos en C++ deben tener tamaño conocido en tiempo de compilación.

Sin embargo, algunos compiladores admiten arreglos de tamaño variable, como [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) o [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#vla). El de [Microsoft](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c11-and-c17-standard-support-arriving-in-msvc/#variable-length-arrays) no.

Para producir código portable deberías crear el arreglo en el montón o usar algún [contenedor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), por ejemplo [`vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (este sí es un *vector*, así se llama).

---

Con memoria dinámica:

```
int* notas = new int[trabajos];

...

// No te olvides de liberar la memoria cuando termines
delete[] notas;
```

De esta manera puedes escoger libremente el tamaño del arreglo, pero no podrás cambiarlo. Con un `vector` no tienes esta limitación.

Puedes establecer el tamaño inicial de un vector y utilizarlo como un arreglo:

```
std::vector<int> notas(tamaño_inicial);

notas[0] = nota1;
notas[1] = nota2;
...
```

O que vaya creciendo a medida que insertas valores en él:

```
std::vector<int> trabajos;

trabajos.push_back(nota1);
trabajos.push_back(nota2);
...
```

Comment: muchas gracias la verdad siempre programe en codeblocks y en devc++ y ahora que hice la trancision  vs me parecia muy raro que no me dejara.